# Mongodb persistent storage causing connection issues

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using `Mongodb` on some flavor of `Linux` on a work sever. I have been using it without any issues for months. Now I can't access the database. It seems that including a volume for persistent storage is somehow stalling the database creation. Here is my YAML:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./mongodata:/data/db
    command: [--auth]
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

If mongodata is empty or doesn't exist upon spinning up the container I can logon to the container but can't get to the mongo CLI:

```
# mongo -u root
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-10-20T01:56:43.161+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error conne
cting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-10-20T01:56:43.163+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-10-20T01:56:43.163+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

and get a log that looks like:

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 27
2020-10-20T02:48:54.485+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-10-20T02:48:54.488+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-10-20T02:48:54.493+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=27 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=c0fd7ba5c8c2
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-10-20T02:48:54.494+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017, tls: { mode: "disabled" } }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/proc/1/fd/1" } }
```

If I comment out the `volume` section in the compose file, I connect to the mongo CLI as expected and the log looks like:

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28
2020-10-20T02:55:07.804+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-10-20T02:55:07.807+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=28 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=589587d99ce2
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-10-20T02:55:07.817+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017, tls: { mode: "disabled" } }, processManagem
ent: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/proc/1/fd/1" } }
2020-10-20T02:55:07.819+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2020-10-20T02:55:07.819+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-10-20T02:55:07.819+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2020-10-20T02:55:07.819+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=31621M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000
,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=
(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-10-20T02:55:08.493+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1603162508:493631][28:0x7f3663ebcb00], txn-recover: Set global recovery tim
estamp: (0, 0)

** continues for a lot of lines **
```

So, it seems that including a volume for persistent storage stalls the creation of the database. Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this will be frustrating for those who come here trying to find a solution. I used the sleep-on-it method and it worked in the morning. I have no idea why. I reset the docker daemon the day before and that did not help. Looking at the server logs, it was not restarted over night. I cannot figure out why but this issue magically disappeared.